# SQL Server query plan sort operator cost spikes when column count increased

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I use a ROW_NUMBER() function inside a CTE that causes a SORT operator in the query plan. This SORT operator has always been the most expensive element of the query, but has recently spiked in cost after I increased the number of columns read from the CTE/query.

What confuses me is the increase in cost is not proportional to the column count. I can increase the column count without much issue, normally. However, it seems my query has past some threshold and now costs so much it has **doubled** the query execution time from 1hour to 2hour+.

I can't figure out what has caused the spike in cost and it's having an impact on business. Any ideas or next steps for troubleshooting you can advise?

Here is the query (simplified):

```
WITH versioned_events AS (
    SELECT [event].* 
        ,CASE WHEN [event].[handle_space] IS NOT NULL THEN [inv].[involvement_id]
            ELSE [event].[involvement_id]
         END AS [derived_involvement_id]

        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [event_id], [event_version] ORDER BY [event_created_date] DESC, [timestamp] DESC ) AS [latest_version]

    FROM [database].[schema].[event_table] [event]
    LEFT JOIN [database].[schema].[involvement] as [inv]                            
    ON [event].[service_delivery_id] = [inv].[service_delivery_id]
        AND [inv].[role_type_code] = 't'                                        
        AND [inv].latest_involvement = 1
    
    WHERE event.deletion_type IS NULL AND (event.handle_space IS NULL
        OR (event.handle_space NOT LIKE 'x%' 
        AND event.handle_space NOT LIKE 'y%')) 
)

INSERT INTO db.schema.table (
      ....
)
SELECT
      ....
 FROM versioned_events AS [event] 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT service_delivery_id, derived_involvement_id 
    FROM versioned_events
    WHERE latest_version = 1
    WHERE ([versioned_events].[timestamp] > '2022-02-07 14:18:09.777610 +00:00')
) AS [delta_events]
ON COALESCE([event].[service_delivery_id],'NULL') = COALESCE([delta_events].[service_delivery_id],'NULL')
AND COALESCE([event].[derived_involvement_id],'NULL') = COALESCE([delta_events].[derived_involvement_id],'NULL')
WHERE [event].[latest_version] = 1
```

Here is the query plan from the version with the most columns that experiences the cost spike (all others look the same except this operator takes much less time (40-50mins):

[image]

I did a comparison of three executions, each with different column counts in the `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM` clause. I can't share the spreadsheet, but I will try convey my findings so far. The following is true of the query with the most columns:

- It takes more than twice as long to execute than the other two executions
- It performs more logical & physical reads and scans
- It has more CPU time
- It reads the most from Tempdb
- The increase in execution time is not proportional with the increase in reads or other mentioned metrics

It is true that there is a memory spill level 8 happening. I have tried updating statistics, but it didn't help and all the versions of the query suffer the same problem so like-for-like is still compared.

I know it can be hard to help with this kind of problem without being able to poke around but I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the direction for what to check / try next.

P.S. the table it reads from is a heap and the table it joins to is indexed. The heap table needs to be a heap otherwise inserts into it will take too long and the problem is kicked down the road.

Also, when I say added more columns, I mean in the SELECT FROM versioned_events statement. The columns are replaced with "...." in the above example.

**UPDATE**

Using a temp table halved the execution time when the column count is the high number that caused the issue but actually takes longer with a reduced column count. It goes back to the idea that a threshold is crossed when the column count is increased :(. In any event, we've used a temp table for now to see if it helps in production.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what happened to cause the performance decrease. You say you select more columns from the CTE? Can you show what exactly changed?

Comment: Have you tried turning the `WITH..` clause into a temporary table (you may need to add an index to it also)?  That should insulate it from the number of columns in the `INSERT ... SELECT ...`.

Comment: In general you are not really giving us enough information for us to be truly helpful.  We cannot even confirm whether it is the big Sort or the little Sort operator that is coming from the `ROW_NUMBER()` column, let alone anything deeper/more useful.  I mean, I understand the difficulties of protecting proprietary information while trying to get help with a complex query like this, I have been there.  I'm just saying that at this point all we can really do is make guesses and throw out random suggestions.

Comment: As an experiment, please put the filter on the date down into the CTE to see if that materially changes performance of the query.

Comment: @HoneyBadger added a note at the end explaining

Comment: @HelloWorld if you are not selecting columns from a cte, sql server won't fetch them. So the answer is likely in those new columns. Maybe there's an index that's not covering anymore, for example.

Comment: It would probably also help if you could explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Please share the relevant query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also add table and index definitions to your question

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT I don't think I could without breaking the business rules. All the records need to be selected in entirety unrestricted by date in the CTE so that they can all be versioned. Adding the DATE filter to CTE would likely cut the records read down from 250mill to 100k.

Comment: The row_number, as sql is currently implemented, will block your ability to cut down the number of rows in the sort due to the semantics of the query you are asking - the filter from one side isn't being pushed below the row_number.  I'm suggesting that you consider if there's a different way to ask the question with slightly different semantics such that you can avoid the sort being bad for you.  So, consider doing a subquery to calculate the max version instead of row_number.

Comment: @RBarryYoung If you remove the ROW_NUMBER(), the big sort disappears and the query is relatively quick. I appreciate the difficulty, I can't even upload the full Query Plan I've been told so at this point I'm happy with random suggestions.

Comment: @HoneyBadger absolutely the answer is in the new columns. Part of the problem is I can't add an index on the table it reads from so that's definitely an issue, but it can't be avoided. 

The code is supposed to, apart from some business rules, it's supposed to mark the latest version of a record based on cols in the ROW_NUMBER. I'm going to try what someone suggested and calculate the versions with a subquery if I can.

Comment: @Charlieface sorry buddy apparently I'm not allowed to share the entire plan. I could recreate the query with new columns names and etc... so details are hidden but I have some other suggestions to try first!

Comment: You can anonymize it with SentryOne Plan Explorer

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.